# How to compare last record and last record - 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have a table from join select like this:

```
No.Transaction   Item Name   PRICE
TC0001           Book        15
TC0001           Pencil      2
TC0001           Eraser      1
TC0002           Book        12
TC0002           Eraser      1.5
TC0003           Pencil      1.8
TC0003           Book        20
```

I want to compare last price and its previous price for same item name. For example `Book is 20 and 12`, `Pencil is 1.8 and 2`

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by compare? What version of sql server are you using?

Answer (score 7):

I think you need a query like this:

```
;WITH t AS (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Item Name] 
                             ORDER BY [No.Transaction] DESC) As seq
    FROM yourTable)
SELECT t1.[Item Name]
    , t1.PRICE As lastPrice
    , t2.PRICE As preLastPrice
    , t1.PRICE - ISNULL(t2.PRICE, 0) As changePrice
FROM t t1
    LEFT JOIN
     t t2 ON t1.[Item Name] = t2.[Item Name] AND t1.seq = t2.seq - 1
WHERE (t1.seq = 1);
```

[**[SQL Fiddle Demo]**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25eaa/4)

Answer (score 3):

you must find column for order your result then use `DENSE_RANK()` and get 2 last row like this

```
SELECT *
(
    SELECT transactionId
        ,itm_name
        ,price
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY itm_name ORDER BY created_date DESC) AS [rank]
    FROM tbl
) res
WHERE res.[rank] IN (1,2)
ORDER BY res.[rank]
```

Comment: AFAIK; Using `WHERE res.[rank] < 3` is better and faster, And `DENSE_RANK()` may rank same two or more records, use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead ;).

Answer (score -2):

Query manipulation. Adding group by, limit(2), order DESC . you should get what you needed.

Comment: SQL Server has not any `limit()` function ;).