# Compare N and N-1 record, using Row_NUMBER().. Performance issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to compare [N] and [N-1] record, `Partition By c_id ORDER BY b_id DESC`. Query is executing fine but running really slow for `ROW_NUMBER()` function. most expensive areas are Index seek, Sort for partition and Hash match. Is there any way to write the query to improve performance.

```
Select [N].*,[N-1]* from  
(
    (
        Select p_id,b_id,c_id,cust_name,TNP,TRQI,First_One_Latest 
        from (
            Select p_id, b_id, c_id, cust_name, TNP, TRQI,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By c_id ORDER BY b_id DESC) First_One_Latest 
            from data.Counterparty_Credit_Risk 
            where ISNUMERIC(c_id)=1 
            and cust_src_system=N'SET1' 
        ) As FIRST 
        where FIRST.First_One_Latest=1
    ) As [N] 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        Select p_id,b_id,c_id,cust_name,TNP,TRQI,First_One_Latest 
        from (
            Select p_id,b_id,c_id,cust_name,TNP,TRQI
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By c_id ORDER BY b_id DESC) First_One_Latest 
            from data.Counterparty_Credit_Risk 
            where ISNUMERIC(c_id)=1 
            and cust_src_system=N'SET1' 
        ) As Second 
        where Second.First_One_Latest=2
    ) As [N-1]   
        ON N.c_id = [N-1].c_id 
)
```

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question. The execution plan is the starting point for (most) query performance issues. A common table expression (CTE) would let you generate the row numbers once and then join the resulting rows together. The `mysql` and `sql-server` tags are, as a rule, incompatible (as stated in their descriptions). Do you need a solution that works for both?

Comment: Do you really want _all_ columns from current and prev row? If not, you can use `LAG` function instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate question [How to compare last record and last record - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32323098/4519059) ;).